# How to render exactly two checkbox with map from nested object?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this nested object, I need to render the checkbox Component only two times exactly the number of Luxuries. I tried map inside map but I got 4 checkbox

```js
const Rooms = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    description: 'Chnambre du luxe 1',
    size: '250',
    guests: '4',
    roomType: 'family room',
    luxuries: [
      { id: 1, value: 'pets', checked: false },
      { id: 2, value: 'breackfast', checked: true }
    ],
    picture: 'pictures/pic.jfif',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    description: 'chambre du lux2',
    picture: 'pictures/pic2.jfif',
    price: 2000,
    size: '300',
    guests: '4',
    roomType: 'single room',
    luxuries: [
      { id: 1, value: 'pets', checked: false },
      { id: 2, value: 'breackfast', checked: true }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
<div className="containerInputCheckBox">
  {console.log('this is your table', Rooms.luxuries)}
  {Rooms.map(room =>
    room.luxuries.map(() => (
      <Checkbox handleCheckedElement={handleCheckedElement} />
    ))
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of the nested object?

Comment: So, you're rendering two rooms which both have two luxuries... 2 x 2 = 4, so where is the problem?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi I want to render exactly the number of luxuries only.

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji I provided nested object

Comment: There are 4 luxuries here, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem here ? as @SinanYaman said you have 4 luxuries and that is what being rendered, what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Wich check boxes do you want? 1 single 1 family? If so, which single which doble checks? The 2 single checks? The 2 family check??